# Including non-runnable files in a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I have a gem where I need to incude some assets that are just static files, never run. I have placed them in `mygem/assests`. The only issue is that they are not installed with the gem. I have tried the gemspec option `require_paths` but that hasn't help. How can I include the directory `mygem/assets` in any installation of my gem?

Comment: What is `spec.files` variable set to in your `gemspec`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Should I have my static assets there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by [Rubygems documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files), all files to be included in gem distribution must be listed in `spec.files` array object:

> Example stolen from specification reference:
>
> ```
> spec.files = Dir['lib/   *.rb'] + Dir['bin/*']
> spec.files += Dir['[A-Z]*'] + Dir['test/**/*']
> spec.files.reject! { |fn| fn.include? "CVS" }
> ```